# Appium basic test - ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined

Tags: javascript, react-native, appium

I am trying to run an appium test as described here, https://blog.logrocket.com/testing-your-react-native-app-with-appium/

However, I get an error - how can I get my basic test to work?

```
> webdriverio-sample-appium-tests@1.0.0 test /Users/user/apps/myracnative/appium
> mocha test/basic


ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/apps/myracnative/appium/test/basic/index.js:16:1)
```

Test:

```
index.js

const wd = require("wd");
const jasmine = require("jasmine");
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 600000;
const PORT = 4723;

const config = {
    platformName: "iOS",
    platformVersion: "14.4",
    deviceName: "iPhone 11",
    app: "../../../apps/myracnative.ipa",
    automationName: "XCUITest", // UiAutomator2, Espresso, or UiAutomator1 for Android
};

const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote("localhost", PORT);

beforeAll(async () => {
    await driver.init(config);
});

test("Test Accessibilty Id", async () => {
    expect(
        await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId("Create account")
    ).toBe(true);
    expect(await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId("Log in")).toBe(true);
});
```

Here is a link to my test repo:

https://bitbucket.org/mharrisRAC/appium-example/src/master/

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following changes in your current script as,

1. Updated the test file as `test.js` to get them executed on local,
2. Made the changes in the below script to get them executed on android device with the provided apk file,
3. Added `setImplicitWaitTimeout(50000)` to the driver config,
4. Added `timeout` of `50000` to jest `beforeAll()` function,
5. Added `timeout` of `50000` to mocha test,

```
const wd = require("wd");
const jasmine = require("jasmine");
jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 600000;
const PORT = 4723;

const config = {
    platformName: "android",
    // platformVersion: "11",
    // deviceName: "iPhone 11",
    // app: "../../../apps/myracnative.ipa",
    app: "/Users/ubuntu/Documents/tmp/appium-example/apps/app-release.apk",
    automationName: "uiautomator2", // UiAutomator2, Espresso, or UiAutomator1 for Android
};

const driver = wd.promiseChainRemote("localhost", PORT);

beforeAll(async () => {
    await driver.init(config).setImplicitWaitTimeout(50000);
}, 50000);

test("Test Accessibilty Id", async () => {
    expect(
        await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId("Create a MyRAC account")
    ).toBe(true);
    expect(await driver.hasElementByAccessibilityId("Log in")).toBe(true);
}, 50000);
```

Following is the screenshot to your success script executions.
[image]